# Store XML Data to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have an XML file. I want to save all the data from the XML file to the database

The file structure of XML is like

```
<STORY>
<BYLINE>abc</BYLINE>
<STORYID>123456</STORYID>
</STORY>
```

The code for storing data to database that I am using is

```
$dom = new DOMDOcument();
    $dom->loadXML(equitymarketnews/$zname);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
    $res = $xpath->query("//STORY/");
$allres = array();
foreach($res as $node){
        $result = array();
$byline = mysql_real_escape_string($node->getElementsByTagName("BYLINE")->item(0)->nodeValue);
$storyid = mysql_real_escape_string($node->getElementsByTagName("STORYID")->item(0)->nodeValue);

}
$sql12="insert into equitymarketnews values('$byline','$storyid')"; 
                        mysql_query($sql12);
```

I am getting nothing in my database. All values are *blanks*.
Where am I going wrong?
I think something is wrong with this line

```
$res = $xpath->query("//STORY/");
```

i want to story the data ie  ABC   and  12345  FROm XML File To Table in database

Comment: Okay, but what is your question?

Comment: am getting nothing in my database
where am doing wrong ?

Comment: Well, some debugging is necessary then. Have you tried to output any of the values? Does the extraction work? What values does the query string contain when you output it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what your question is but assuming that the code you posted does not work as you aspect, one thing i noticed is the insertion of the record:

```
$sql12="insert into equitymarketnews values('$byline','$storyid','$pubdate','$author','$cat','$subcat','$titleline','$subtitleline,'$storymain','$flag')"; 
mysql_query($sql12);
```

shouldn't it be **inside** your `foreach` loop? Otherwise you won't get anything into your database.

In my opinion it should look something like that:

```
foreach($res as $node){
        $result = array();
        $byline = mysql_real_escape_string($node->getElementsByTagName("BYLINE")->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $storyid = mysql_real_escape_string($node->getElementsByTagName("STORYID")->item(0)->nodeValue);
        $sql12="insert into equitymarketnews values('$byline','$storyid')"; 
        mysql_query($sql12);
}
```

Comment: Yes i read your edit but if the code in your post is the code you're actually using, the insertion got to be inside your foreach loop. Otherwise your variables will get assigned but no insertion is called for each record. I also edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use mysql client directly for importing XML data. I do not have much experience to provide you with a code sample, but [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html) have quite a bit documentation on it.

Essentially, you can do something like this:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'address.xml' INTO TABLE quitymarketnews ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<STORY>';
```